# The parameter curves are asymptotic curves

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

I am looking at the following exercise:

Let $p$ be a hyperbolic point of a surface $S$.

Show that there is a patch of $S$ containing $p$ whose parameter curves are asymptotic curves.

Show that the second fundamental form of such a patch is of the form $2Mdudv$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

Let $\sigma (u,v)$ be a surface patch of $S$ that contains $p=\sigma (u_0, v_0)$.

Since $p$ is a hyperbolic point of $S$ we have that at $p$ the principal curvatures $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$ are of opposite sign and non-zero.

Since the Gauss curvature is $K=\kappa_1\kappa_2$ we have that at $p$, $K<0$.

$$$$

How could we continue?

$$$$

P.S. A curve $\gamma$ on a surface $S$ is called asymptotic if its normal curvature is everywhere zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $p$ is a hyperbolic point there exists a neighborhood $U_p\subset S$ of $p$ such that $$K(q)<0,\ \forall q\in U_p.$$ Consider now a parametrization of $p$ in $U_p$, i.e. $$X\colon V\subset \mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow U_p\subset S, \ \ (u,v)\mapsto X(u,v),\ \ \&\ p\in X(V),$$ where $V$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Since every point of $X(V)$ is hyperbolic you have exactly two families of asymptotic curves, which you can find by solving the equation $$L(c(t))(u'(t))^2+2M(c(t))u'(t)v'(t)+N(c(t))(v'(t))^2=0,$$ where $$c\colon I\subset \mathbb{R}\rightarrow V,\ t\mapsto c(t)=(u(t),v(t)).$$ Next you change the parameters $(u,v)$ to $(\tilde{u},\tilde{v})$ in the following way: Let $$F\colon V\subset \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$$ the differentiable map that maps the asymptotic curves (of $V$) to parameter curves. By checking that the jacobian determinant of $F$ is $\neq 0$ you can apply the inverse function theorem and consider the parametrization $$Y:=X\circ F^{-1} \colon F(V)\subset \mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow U_p\subset S,\ \ (\tilde{u},\tilde{v})\mapsto Y(\tilde{u},\tilde{v}).$$ Now, the parameter curves of $Y$ are asymptotic curves. Now, due to the parametrization $Y$, we obtain:

- $k_N(Y(\tilde{u},\tilde{v}),Y_\tilde{u}(\tilde{u},\tilde{v}))=0\Rightarrow II_{Y(\tilde{u},\tilde{v})}(Y_{\tilde{u}}(\tilde{u},\tilde{v}))=0\Rightarrow L(\tilde{u},\tilde{v})=0.$
- $k_N(Y(\tilde{u},\tilde{v}),Y_\tilde{v}(\tilde{u},\tilde{v}))=0\Rightarrow II_{Y(\tilde{u},\tilde{v})}(Y_{\tilde{v}}(\tilde{u},\tilde{v}))=0\Rightarrow N(\tilde{u},\tilde{v})=0.$

Thus the second fundamental form of $Y$ is of the desired form: $II=Mu'v'$.

*PS* : By $k_n(p,v)$ we denote the normal curvature at the point $p\in S$ in the direction $v\in T_pS$.

Comment: By "parametrization of $p$ in $U_p$" do you mean that we take a parametrization only for the point $p$, or for all points that are in $U_p$ ? $$$$ Also, at the part "Since every point of $X(V)$ is hyperbolic you have exactly two families of asymptotic curves", I haven't really understood how we concluded to the fact that we have exactly two families of asymptotic curves... Could you explain it to me? $$$$ After that, why do we have to change the parameters?

Comment: First, by "parametrization of $p$ in $U_p$" i mean just a parametrization that contains $p$ and the image is a subset of $U_p$.

Comment: Ah ok... Could you explain to me how we conclude to the fact that we have exactly two families of asymptotic curves?

Comment: First, by "parametrization of $p$ in $U_p$" i mean just a parametrization that contains $p$ and the image is a subset of $U_p$. Second, at each point of $X(V)$ you have exactly two asymptotic directions (that is due to to the fact that each point is hyperbolic). Therefore, by choosing carefully at each point one of the two asymptotic directions you obtain a differentiable vector field whose integral curves are the one family of asymptotic curves. By taking the "other" vector field you obtain the other family of asymptotic curves.

Comment: We have that a curve is asymptotic if its normal curvature is everywhere zero. Does it mean that the normal curvature at an hyperbolic point is zero? I got stuck right now...

Comment: Let $p$ be a point on a regular surface $S$. We say that $v\in T_pS$ is an asymptotic direction at $p$ if the normal curvature of $S$ at $p$ at the direction $v$ vanishes, i.e. $$k_n(p,v)=0.$$ Now, if $c\colon I\subset \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow S$ is an asymptotic curve of $S$ that means that $$k_n(c(s),c'(s))=0,\ \forall s\in I.$$

Comment: Also, if $p$ is a hyperbolic point of $S$ then you have exactly two asymptotic directions at $p$. You can easily prove this from the Euler's formula: $$(k_n(p,v)=:)k_n(\theta)=k_1(p)\cos^2\theta+k_2(p)\sin^2\theta,$$ where $k_1(p)$ and $k_2(p)$ are the principal curvatures at the point $p$ and $\theta$ is the angle of the principal direction $e_1\in T_pS$ with the direction $v\in T_pS$.